# calculate window average without partition or order by column in SQL

Tags: sql, window-functions

If I have a data frame with only number of clicks at certain fixed time interval looking like this:

```
1
3
4
2
6
1
```

And I want to calculate their rolling average with the 5 rows above, would this be legit:

> SELECT AVG(value) OVER (ORDER BY 1 ASC ROWS 4 PRECEDING ) AS avg_value
>   FROM df GROUP BY 1

Or should it be

> SELECT AVG(value) OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ASC ROWS 4 PRECEDING) AS
>   avg_value FROM df GROUP BY 1

Comment: Not legit, because your data is lacking a second column which you'd need to tell the order of each number of clicks.  There is no internal "order" to a SQL table, in general.

Comment: given the lack of order, is there a way to add a row number then do rolling avg?

Comment: Yes, but row number itself requires a column for the order.  You need to record your clicks with a timestamp.  This is really your only option.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
SELECT df.*,
       AVG(value) OVER (ORDER BY datetimecol ASC
                        ROWS 4 PRECEDING
                       ) AS avg_rolling_5
FROM df;
```

Notes:

- A rolling average requires implies an ordering on the data.  The `datetimecol` is for the column that represents that ordering.
- A rolling average is for the *original* data, not the aggregated data, so no `order by` is needed.
- SQL databases have *tables*, not *dataframes*.